# Merge CSV row with a string match from a 2nd CSV file

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I'm working with two large files; approximately 100K+ rows each and I want to search csv file #1 for a string contained in csv file#2, then join another string from csv file#1 to the row in csv file#2 based on the match criteria. Here's an example of the data I'm working with and my expected output:

File#1: String to be matched in file#2 is the 2nd element; 1st is to be appended to each matched row in file#2. **(Integer to be appended is bold; string to be matched is italicized for clarity only)**

row 1:

> **3604430123**,*mta0000cadd503c.mta.net*

row 2:

> **3604434567**,*mta0000CADD5638.MTA.NET*

row 3:

> **3606304758**,*mta00069234e9a51.DT.COM*

File#2:

row 1:

> 4246,211-015617,*mta0000cadd503c.mta.net*,old,NW MG2,BBand2 ESA,Active

row 2:

> 7251,ACCOUNT,*mta0000CADD5638.MTA.NET*,FQDN ,NW MG2,BBand2 ESA,Active

row 3:

> 536887946,874-22558501,*mta00069234e9a51.DT.COM*,"P",NW MG2,BBand2 ESA,Active

Desired Output joining bold integer string from file#1 to entire row in file#2 based on string match between file#1 and file#2:

row 1:

> 4246,211-015617,*mta0000cadd503c.mta.net*,old,NW MG2,BBand2 ESA,Active,**3604430123**

row 2:

> 7251,ACCOUNT,*mta0000CADD5638.MTA.NET*,FQDN ,NW MG2,BBand2 ESA,Active,**3604434567**

row 3:

> 536887946,874-22558501,*mta00069234e9a51.DT.COM*,"P",NW MG2,BBand2 ESA,Active,**3606304758**

There are many instances where the case in the match string of file#1 doesn't match the case of file#2, however the characters match, thus case can be ignored for match critera. The character case does need to be preserved in file#2 after it is appended with the integer string from file#1.

I'm a python newb and I've been at this for a while and have scoured posts in SE, but can't seem to come up with working code that gets me to the point where I can just print out a line from file#2 that has been matched on the string in file#1. I've tried a few other methods, such as writing to a dictionary, using Dictreader, etc, but haven't been able to clear what appears to be simple errors in those methods, so I tried to strip this down to simple lists and get to the point where I can use a list comprehension to combine the data, then write that back to a file named output, which will eventually be written back to a csv file. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv

sg = []
fqdn = []
output = []
with open(r'file2.csv', 'rb') as src:
    read = csv.reader(src, delimiter=',')
    for row in read:
        sg.append(row)

with open(r'file1.csv', 'rb') as src1:
    read1 = csv.reader(src1, delimiter=',')
    for row in read1:
        fqdn.append(row)


output = output.append([s[0] for s in sg if fqdn[1] in sg])

print output
```

Result after running this is:

> None
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: output.append modifies output in-place and returns None. Also you should use `.extend()` instead of `.append()`. `append` appends one item to the list, while `extend` appends all the items in a list or iterable to the list. Also it's easier to start with a for loop instead of a comprehension in most cases, as in comprehensions you tend to squeeze too much into a line, which quickly gets confusing, especially if you are new to the language. See my answer for a solution with a simple for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a dictionary for file#1 than just a list, as matching is easier. Just turn `fqdn` into a dict and in your loop reading file#1 set your key-value pairs on the dict. I would use `.lower()` on the match key. This turns the key to lower case so you later only have to check if the lower-cased version of the field in file#2 is a key in the dictionary:

```
import csv

sg = []
fqdn = {}
output = []
with open(r'file2.csv', 'rb') as src:
    read = csv.reader(src, delimiter=',')
    for dataset in read:
        sg.append(dataset)

with open(r'file1.csv', 'rb') as src1:
    read1 = csv.reader(src1, delimiter=',')
    for to_append, to_match in read1:
        fqdn[to_match.lower()] = to_append

for dataset in sg:
    to_append = fqdn.get(dataset[2].lower()) # If the key matched, to_append now contains the string to append, else it becomes None
    if to_append:
        dataset.append(to_append) # Append the field
        output.append(dataset) # Append the row to the result list

print(output)
```

You can then use `csv.writer` to create a csv file from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force solution to solving this problem. For every line of the first file, you will search through every line of the second file until you find a match. The matched lines will be written out to the output.csv file in the format you specified using the csv writer.

```
import csv

with open('file1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    with open('file2.csv', 'r') as file2:
        with open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
            reader2 = csv.reader(file2)

            for row in reader1:
                if not row:
                    continue

                for other_row in reader2:
                    if not other_row:
                        continue

                    # if we found a match, let's write it to the csv file with the id appended
                    if row[1].lower() == other_row[2].lower():
                        new_row = other_row
                        new_row.append(row[0])
                        writer.writerow(new_row)
                        continue

                # reset file pointer to beginning of file
                file2.seek(0)
```

You might be tempted to store the information in a data structure before writing it out to a file. In my experience, you always end up getting larger files in the future and may run into memory issues. I like to write things out to file as I find the matches in order to avoid this problem.

Comment: Seems to work in my small test files, but my resulting output file has blank rows in between each entry. How would I modify your code to remove these blank rows. Could I simply add a sort() or something like that to eliminate them? Also, I'm using python 2.7, so I think i should be opening the csv file with "wb", correct?

Comment: I wonder if you have newline characters in the second field of file 1? I wouldn't suggest using a sort to solve this. Try to actually remove the extra newlines before writing it out to the file. The writerow method will automatically add the necessary newline, so you must have an extra one coming from somewhere.

Comment: Found it...so I just tried running it on the full size files where file1 is about 1.5M and file2 is 9.7M and it runs really slow...i stopped it after 10min to check it and the output looks correct so that's good. What could I do to speed it up? I'm running it on OK hardware - intel i7 w/ 16G Ram...nothing running in the background.

Comment: I think you could get huge speed gains by loading file2 into a database with an index on the field you are matching on to make searches very fast. You could try loading your csv file directly into sqlite: https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

Instead of looping through the second file, you perform searches on the database to find matches.